# Create a library in iPhone project

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a problem with my iPhone program.
I have imported a folder into my project.
I use the class into the folder like the other class.
But now i want create a library with these folder because is a external project and i want use it in other project.
There are a solutions for these problem?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new project with Xcode, you can choose to create a library for iPhone OS, and Xcode will create a project for a static library for iPhone OS.
Once you created the project, you need to import the files you already have, or paste the code in the files Xcode created for you.

[image: New Project]

Create two different Xcode projects; in one you put the code for the application, and in the other you put the code of the library.
When you compile the code for the application, you add a reference to the library you compiled from the second project.

Comment: but i have create an application and now i want creare a librery for these.
how can do these?